# Multiple Desktop Icons in InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup

I am creating an installer that has a bonus application in with the normal application. I have the icon showing in the program group just fine, I want to be able to give the option to create a desktop icon for BOTH applications. Currently, my options seem to be no desktop icon, or if I create one, it seems to only want to create the second app and not the first...

Help?

Thank you
Dave

Answer (score 6):

If you only want one option, copy the existing `[Icon]` entry (with the desktopicon task) and change the name. If only one is appearing, you most likely have the same name set for both of them so it's being overwritten.

If you want to individual options, also duplicate the `[Tasks]` entry and change the name and second icon to suit.

(Next time, please post a sample of the code that's causing a problem)